# Why isn't my migration run from PyCharm affecting my local db?

Tags: python, django, pycharm, migration, database-migration

I'm using PyCharm 2018.2 with Python 3.7.  I have defined my database in my settings.py file ...

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mainsite',
        'USER': 'mainsite',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

And using "Option + R" on my Mac, I can bring up the "manage.py" console, where I wish to run a migration.  I do so by running the following.  It appears to be successful ...

```
manage.py@mainsite_project > sqlmigrate mainsite 0002
bash -cl "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainsite_project/venv/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py sqlmigrate mainsite 0002 /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainsite_project"
Tracking file by folder pattern:  migrations
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainsite_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
BEGIN;
--
-- Add field url to article
--
ALTER TABLE "mainsite_article" ADD COLUMN "url" text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE "mainsite_article" ALTER COLUMN "url" DROP DEFAULT;
COMMIT;
Process finished with exit code 0
```

However, when I look at my database locally, I don't see the extra column added in there ...

```
mainsite=> \d mainsite_article;

                                     Table "public.mainsite_article"
    Column    |           Type           |                           Modifiers                            
--------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 id           | integer                  | not null default nextval('mainsite_article_id_seq'::regclass)
 path         | character varying(100)   | not null
 time         | timestamp with time zone | not null
 votes        | integer                  | not null
 comments     | integer                  | not null
 main_page    | boolean                  | not null
Indexes:
    "mainsite_article_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "mainsite_mainsitestat" CONSTRAINT
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sqlmigrate` just prints out the SQL for the migration. Use `migrate` to actually run the migration.

Comment: Doh!  Thanks, taht was it.